# Why do users remain logged in after .NET Core application restart?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, session, cookies

We are using **.NET Core 3.1** to develop a web application. We log in users with `HttpContext.SignInAsync` and sign them out with `HttpContext.SignOutAsync`. During development, we tried running application on IIS Express and inside Docker container. In both cases user remains logged in even after application restart. Why does this happen? How can we automatically "invalidate" all logged in users so they will be forced to log in again once the application is restarted/redeployed? Which piece of code in our configuration (in `Startup`?) causes the user to remain logged in after application restart?

`Startup.cs`

```cs
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            options.Cookie.Name = ".UserLogin-Web.Session";
            options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
        });

        services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddCookie(options =>
            {
                options.LoginPath = "/Home/Index";
                options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Error/403";
            });

        services.AddControllersWithViews();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseSession();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

`LoginModel.cs`

```cs
public class LoginModel
{
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

`Index.cshtml`

```html
@model UserLogin.Web.Models.LoginModel

@using System.Security.Claims

@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    <p>Display name: @User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Name)</p>
    <p>Email: @User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email)</p>
    <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Logout">Log out</a>
}
else
{
    <form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Login" method="POST">
        <label>Display name</label>
        <input asp-for="DisplayName" type="text" />

        <label>Email</label>
        <input asp-for="Email" type="email" />

        <input type="submit" value="Login" />
    </form>
}
```

`HomeController.cs`

```cs
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginModel loginModel)
    {
        var claims = new List<Claim>()
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, loginModel.DisplayName),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, loginModel.Email)
        };

        ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

        AuthenticationProperties authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
        {
            AllowRefresh = true,
            ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(60),
            IsPersistent = true,
            IssuedUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow
        };

        await HttpContext.SignInAsync(
            CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
            new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity),
            authProperties
        );

        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
    {
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it's the data protection provider storing its generated keys somewhere persistent, which allows the issued cookies to be valid.

Comment: Can we somehow disable just the login persistence without affecting other parts of the application which use data protection (AFAIK `TempData`, anti-forgery tokens, etc.)?

Comment: You can specify a data protection provider for cookie auth in the AddCookie(options => { }) callback. That would probably allow you to put in an in-memory provider.

Comment: Yes, that would probably be it! I tried with `options.DataProtectionProvider = new EphemeralDataProtectionProvider()` and it seems to work fine.

Comment: Note if you deploy to multiple parallel instances, each of them will get different keys and won't accept cookies issued by each other. If that is not a scenario for you then the ephemeral provider should work fine.

Comment: At the moment, we deploy only 1 parallel instance. Which approach do you recommend for the future when we decide to deploy multiple parallel instances? On each application deploy/restart, user should be logged out.